# .net, soap, web services, How to override the serialization\conversion in a web reference

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am accessing a third-party web service written in php.
The service wsdl is added as a web reference in my project and works ok most of the times.

Now a problem I often run into is the following :

The parameters in the wsdl have their type defined (string, bool, int), but they don't have the nillable attribute set. Now often int or bool are returned as empty elements in the response, which throws a conversion error :

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9594283
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
   System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s) +43
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReadernutritionService.Read6_NullableOfInt32(Boolean checkType) +125
```

What I do now to fix this is change all parameter types to string's, so they don't throw errors on empty elements. I don't like this solution at all, so I was wondering if I could override this somehow so that when the element is empty, I can simply fill in 0 for int, and false for bool.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Im pretty sure the WSDL would be invalid - it does allow for nullable (nillable) types and if it doesn't specify that than WSDL and service do not match.  You could modify the WSDL, or contact the web service vendor

Comment: That is the whole problem, I don't have access to the wsdl. And they are not planning on changing the wsdl for me, I already asked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make a local copy of the WSDL, make the required changes and then call that. You could attempt to get fancy and write scripts that do this dynamically, but you probably are asking for more trouble than its worth.

Comment: That could be an alternative solution, but I'm referencing 10 different wsdl files with each a huge number of elements. I would prefer a solution where I can manipulate the conversion of each element in the deserialization.